# Mostrar DIV de acordo com a condição em PHP

Tags: php, div

Tenho uma `div` que traz um `select` do banco, mas ela só pode ser mostrada se atender a uma condição. Ela vem assim:

```
<div id="conteudo" style="display: none;">
```

Caso ela atenda a essa condição: 
`if (get('data_do_descredenciamento') != '')`, então o display da `div` deve mudar para `style="display: show;"`.

Como posso montar essa condição no PHP?

Comment: Em vez de esconder a div não é mais simples nem colocar ela na saída?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opção 1:

```
<div style="<?php echo get('data_do_descredenciamento') != '' ? 'show' : 'none'; ?>">
</div>
```

Opção 2:

```
<div style="<?php if (get('data_do_descredenciamento') == '') { echo 'display: none;' }">
</div>
```

Opção 3:

```
<?php if (get('data_do_descredenciamento') != '') { ?>
    <div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Só sugerindo uma melhoria, o retorno `show` é desnecessário, poderia ser trocado por `null` por que a opção `show` dentro da propriedade `display` não existe.